# JQuery Deferred resolve if at least one of the requests get resolved

Tags: jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

Let's say I want to create one master Deferred object that contains at least 2 Deferred objects. This master Deferred object must be resolved **if at least one** of the child Deferred objects get resolved. How can I do this with JQuery?

I know that if I do something like that

```
function resolveMaster(){
    var requests = [];
    requests.push(request1);
    requests.push(request2);
    return $.when.apply($, requests);
}
```

Then it will be resolved if all of the requests get resolved.

This is what I want to do. Ajax requests inside those functions should be resolved if request succeeds **AND** the array returned is not empty (!important).

```
//request1 is different from request2
request1 : function() {
    var dfd = new jQuery.Deferred();
    $.ajax({
        url : "someURL",
        success : function(data) {
            if (data && data.length > 0) {
                //some code here
                dfd.resolve(data); //this is important here
            } else {
                dfd.reject();
            }
        },
        error : function() {
            dfd.reject();
        }
    });
    return dfd.promise();
}


//request2 is different from request1
request2 : function() {
    var dfd = new jQuery.Deferred();
    $.ajax({
        url : "someURL",
        success : function(data) {
            if (data && data.length > 0) {
                //some code here
                dfd.resolve(data); //this is important here
            } else {
                dfd.reject();
            }
        },
        error : function() {
            dfd.reject();
        }
    });
    return dfd.promise();
}
```

Comment: and what if _none_ of the promises are resolved?

Comment: at least one indicates that one or more is resolved, which means that if 0 then master is rejected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is commonly called `any` or `some` and is not implemented in jQuery itself.

Luckily, you can easily implement this yourself.

```
 function any(promises){
      var d = $.Deferred(); // new promise
      // on the first success - resolve it
      for(var i = 0;i < promises.length; i++) promises[i].then(d.resolve);
      // this is enough since a promise is immutable after it resolves and if we 
      // call it more than once it will keep the original value
      return d.promise(); // return the promise we created
 }
```

Or in short:

```
 function any(promises){
      var d = $.Deferred(); 
      for(var i = 0; i < promises.length; i++) promises[i].then(d.resolve);
      return d.promise(); 
 }

 // then you can do
 any([$.ajax("firstUrl"), $.ajax("secondUrl")]).then(function(response){
        // response from whichever finished first.
 });
```

Also note, $.ajax already returns a promise, so you don't need a deferred around it - you can simply `return $.ajax` and get the same result as you do with your whole `Deferred`/`success:` thing

If you additionally want to reject if all promise reject - you can do it as such:

```
 function any(promises){
      var d = $.Deferred(); 
      var sem = promises.length;
      for(var i = 0; i < promises.length; i++){
         promises[i].fail(function(el){
              sem--; 
              if(sem === 0) d.reject(el); // reject all, with last's error
          }).then(d.resolve);
      }
      return d.promise(); 
 }
```

Comment: he's returning a new promise so that he can `reject` based on a response that in AJAX-terms would usually be considered resolved.

Comment: @Alnitak Right, so he should `$.ajax(...).then(function(data){ return (data && data.length > 0) ? data : $.Deferred().reject(); })`

Comment: Yes, that would be more idiomatic these days.

Comment: @Alnitak definitely, that's way more readable with braces. Totally missed that - thanks.

Comment: Just thinking out loud, but I wonder whether the `any` resolution ought to wait until all of the passed promises are either deferred or rejected?  Doing it as soon as there's a single `resolved` means you can't be sure whether other outstanding promises might get resolved later.

Comment: Because you don't want to wait for it, it could take a _lot_ more time for all of them to settle. You can always explicitly `$.when.apply` then later if you wanna check if they all resolved or not.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer, everything works as expected (Y)
But next time read the question more carefully, because I even made some places bold to explain why I am creating Deferred object for Ajax requests.

Comment: @walts read the comments more carefully yourself!  Benjamin has explained there how you can achieve the same effect but only explicitly creating a new `$.Deferred()` in the "fake reject" case.

Comment: I read them but in his answer he said that 'Also note, $.ajax already returns a promise, so you don't need a deferred around it - you can simply return $.ajax and get the same result as you do with your whole Deferred/success: thing' which indicates that he did not read question carefully

Comment: @walts I did, and when asked to clarify I clarified - like I said in the second comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26778203/jquery-deferred-resolve-if-at-least-one-of-the-requests-get-resolved/26778408#comment42135163_26778408 . Sorry if you feel I didn't pay enough attention to the question, it happens to me sometimes :)